# Packing the log using Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging Block

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I am using the RollingFlatFileTraceListener to save the log files. Configuration of the listener is like this:

```
<listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="log/ReferentNet.log" footer="" formatter="Text Formatter"
        header="" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollSizeKB="1024"
        timeStampPattern="" maxArchivedFiles="10" traceOutputOptions="Callstack" />
</listeners>
```

The question is, can I somehow enable packing (e.g. into .zip files) of the archived files.
I want roller not to simply roll the files, but to pack them except the last one.

This is rather a standard feature... For example, Poco Foundation library, which I use for my C++ projects, is capable of this.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that is not a feature of the RollingFlatFileTraceListener or any other FlatFileTraceListener built into Enterprise Library. You would have to implement your own CustomTraceListener to enable file compression.